# Как просмотреть пакеты в докере через wireshark

Tags: docker, wireshark

Предыстория.

Есть контейнер "dns", в котором крутится кеширующий dns-резолвер `unbound`. Я хочу очищать данные по определенной зоне ("site.com") из **другого** контейнера "api".

Для этого в составе резолвера "dns" есть утилита `unbound-control`, которая вызывается так:

```
unbound-control flush_zone site.com.
```

Также есть порт `8953`, который служит для удаленного управления демоном.

Я хочу вызывать команду `flush_zone site.com.` из другого контейнера. Пробовал делать так:

```
/srv # telnet dns 8953
Connected to dns
flush_zone site.com.
Connection closed by foreign host
```

Результат очистки зоны я не получил.

По-идее, конечно, нужно поставить утилиту `unbound-control` во второй контейнер "api", и использовать ее возможность управления по сети. Но мне не хочется тащить еще один пакет в контейнер.

Поэтому я хочу узнать, что нужно отправить в dns:8953, что бы это привело к очистке кеша. Информации по протоколу `unbound-control` я не нашел. Разбираться в [сорцах](https://github.com/jedisct1/unbound/blob/master/smallapp/unbound-control.c) не умею. И поэтому решил проснифить пакеты.

Итак, как из командной строки в докер контейнере запустить wireshark на прослушку 8953 порта, а затем посмотреть, что там отправлялось при вызове утилиты?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь tcpdump и даже если не поймете что к чему "на месте" - можете вывод отправить в файл, а уже потом анализировать его с помощью wireshark .

Comment: @zalex, хорошая идея, можете подсказать ключики с которыми запускать?

Comment: Нет, ключи я сейчас не подскажу, там попросту можете отфильтровать по порту и интерфейсу и этого обудет достаточно. Однако я считаю что вы сами себе придумали проблему и написал по этому поводу ответ.

Comment: У wireshark имеется конслльня версия тоже. Немного примеров по tcpdump https://github.com/Hellseher/cix/blob/master/spices/cix-tcpdump.org

Comment: @Hellseher, я уже нашел ответ на вопрос через `tcdump`. Я знаю про консольную версию, но не знаю как ей воспользоваться, все что смотрел - использует gui. Если вы можете написать ответ именно по wireshark в консоли, я буду рад.

Comment: Терминальная версия это  `tshark` примеры можно глянуть тут https://hackertarget.com/tshark-tutorial-and-filter-examples/
еще по теме хорошая утилта https://github.com/secdev/scapy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение подсказано zalex - использовать `tcpdump`. Команда такая:

```
tcpdump -x -s 65535 -w dump.log host 10.1.0.105 and port 8953
```

После этого осталось скормить полученный лог `wireshark`.

То что я искал:

```
UBCT1 flush_zone site.com.
```

Подсказку можно было найти и в [сорцах](https://github.com/jedisct1/unbound/blob/master/smallapp/unbound-control.c):

```
snprintf(pre, sizeof(pre), "UBCT%d ", UNBOUND_CONTROL_VERSION);
remote_write(ssl, fd, pre, strlen(pre));
for(i=0; i<argc; i++) {
    remote_write(ssl, fd, space, strlen(space));
    remote_write(ssl, fd, argv[i], strlen(argv[i]));
}
```

Решение для NodeJS:

```
async purgezone(domain) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let client = new net.Socket();

    let timer = setTimeout(() => {
      client.destroy();
      resolve();
    }, 500);

    client.on('data', (data) => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      client.destroy();
      resolve();
    });

    client.connect(8953, ownDns, () => {
      client.write(`UBCT1 flush_zone ${domain}.\n`);
    });


  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В ответе же напишу о том что утилита о которой вы говорите unbound-control не является демоном и конечно же не управляется ни как удаленно.

Порт о котором вы говорите это порт непосредственно демона, коим является unbound. Вот тут вы можете даже посмотреть его ман и увидите что именно 8953 есть тот порт, через который управляется демон. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/unbound.conf.5.html

По сему считаю что вы высосали проблему из пальца и нет ровно ни одной причины почему бы вам не поставить управляющую утилиту во второй контейнер ибо она предназначенна именно для того, для чего вы хотите ее использовать.

Comment: Да, я ошибся, не утилитой, а демоном, сейчас поправлю вопрос. Но утилиту тащить в контейнер не хочется. Причина банальная - уже есть либа для работы с сетью, я просто хочу подключиться по сети, отправить команду, отключиться. А не запускать предназначенную для этого утилиту.

Comment: @TotalPusher я все равно не вижу банальности кроме того что вы по какой то причине не хотите так делать. 
Какие минусы вы видете в том что подтянете сто килобайтную утилиту? Ну или сколько она занимает ? Мегабайт ? 
Или вы считаете что упадет производительность ? Или надежность ? 
У нас на работе есть сотрудник. который считает себя прям "тру админ". И вот я понимаю что четверть своего времени он тратит на набор путей чтобы посмотреть или перейти к папке с файлами, вместо того чтобы поставить хотя бы ranger.  Ну вот как буд-то бы это из той же оперы, уж простите.

Comment: спасибо за tcdump, я уже нашел команду. Это `UBCT1 flush_zone site.com.`. Я не думаю что упадет скорость, так как замер дает 0 секунд при вызове тулзы. А теперь вот почему: 1. мне было интересно, это мой пет-проект. И теперь я знаю как действовать в более сложных случаях 2. Для запуска тулзы нужно написать чуть больше кода, я уже обвязал кучу утилит тем способом, что вы предлагаете. Теперь попробовать другой.

Comment: а что за `ranger`?

Comment: @TotalPusher консольный файловый менеджер.

Comment: Я, в основном, живу в консоли, в zsh, но против двухпанельников, для определённых задач, ничего не имею. Правда Ranger не зашёл, а вот vifm очень и очень годная штука оказалась.